# viewpager take time to load fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've a viewpager with just 2 fragments.The first fragment has a looong scrollview with different "include" in it.I notice that for load this 2 fragments the viewpager takes a long time.
There is a solution for this issue?
I have this viewpager in a fragment inside a drawer,and this fragment is loaded when the onDrawerClosed is called.
For this "lag" i've was thinking to use a progressbar in this way...

```
<ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/dialogPreLoading"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:visibility="gone" >
```

...so using setVisible(View.GONE) or setVisible(View.VISIBLE) i can show or hide the progressbar,also for the viewpager, in this way:
at start: viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         preLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

and after : viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           preLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

The problem is the "after" ...when and where i can set visible the viewpager and gone the progressbar?There is a way to understand if a fragment is loaded in a viewpager inside the viewpager fragment?
For now i've done an asynktask that after 3000 mills make this VISIBLE/GONE settings...but i don't like this solution :/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you doing some IO or other Long running Tasks in the Fragment loaded.

You can use Loaders or AsyncTasks or other to not interrupt the Main Thread to load your Fragments.

Have a look eg. at the [Loader Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html):